# Linux ./configure won't detect java or javac

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javac, configure

I'm trying to install a library in Linux that has bindings for Java.
As such, I used `apt-get install` to get both the java jdk 6 and 7.
However, when I run the configure, I keep getting this message and the library doesn't install what it needs for java.

```
checking which interfaces are enabled... cxx c ocaml java
checking for javac... no
checking for java... no
checking for jar... no
checking for javah... no
configure: WARNING: unable to include <jni.h>
```

From the command line, both java and javac work.
I'm not sure what else to do.  Any guidance?
Thanks.

Edit:  This is on an Ubuntu setup.  Not sure where the Debian keyword came from.

Comment: Use update-java-alternatives to setup your jdk. Make sure it's a jdk and not a jre.

Comment: See how it checks. It may be as simple as exporting JAVA_HOME, set to the root dir of the installation of one of the SDKs, the parent of bin/, jre/, lib/ etc.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Or `update-alternatives --config java`. There is no symlink for `update-java-alternatives` on RHEL 6.5 at least. (understanding that OP is using Debian).

Comment: Download jdk from oracle website, and install it by yourself, then use `which java` to check installation.

Comment: @staticx saw apt-get in question.

Comment: Updated the original question.  I'm not sure where the Debian keyword came from, but this is on Ubuntu.
The actual command I used was: <code>apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk</code>.  I did this for both 6 and 7.
I'll look into the update-java-alternatives, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `update-java-alternatives` pushed me in the right direction.
I tried `which java` but it only told me: `/usr/bin`.

I used `update-java-alternatives -l` and it outputted where the jdk was installed:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

From there, I could use the command:

```
./configure --with-java=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

It found my jdk after that.
Thanks for the help everyone.